# ng-click does not work in angular-ui-grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to fire a click event when a cell in ui-grid is clicked but the ng-click isn't working. Also ng-class isn't working and I can't get width: '*' to work. Does anyone know of any *accurate* documentation for angular-ui-grid? I'm using angular v 1.5.11 and angular-ui-grid v 4.2.3. It seems like half the features of ui-grid don't work and the docs don't seem to explain why.

```
{ name: 'Number of Vendor Parts', field: 'xrefCount', enableFiltering: false,
      cellTemplate: '<div ng-class="{inactive: row.entity.active === \'N\'}" ' +
                         'ng-click="grid.appScope.showCrossReference()">' +
                      '<a>{{ row.entity.xrefCount }}</a>' +
                    '</div>'
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R5izcuidNc7MfG2K5RV6?p=preview). I think your problem is that you have not added you controller after *grid.appScope*. If you declare you controller like this:

```
ng-controller="MainCtrl as main"
```

The expression for *ng-click* should look like this:

```
grid.appScope.main.showCrossReference(grid, row)
```

Note that you can pass to the function the grid and the row of the clicked button.

As you can see in the plunker for *ng-class* I use a function which returns the name of the css class using the *row* parameter.